# Ruby hash bug, anomality or normal?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Is the following, a Ruby bug or perfectly normal?

```
> a = [1, 2, 3].zip([[]]*3).to_h
=> {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}
> a[1] << 2
=> [2]
> a
=> {1=>[2], 2=>[2], 3=>[2]}
```

I do not expect all values to get appended by `2` as I only meant to add `2` in the place where key is `1`.

Comment: In Python, this would happen because `[[]]*3` results in a list of three of the same list (same object). Thus, when you append to it, it shows up in all the keys. Using `[[], [], []]` would not result in this issue, but I don't know enough Ruby to know if it's the same.

Comment: What's the object _id of each value in the hash?

Comment: They all have same `object_id`

Comment: I see why this is so now. What's the workaround to achieve the same functionality? For example I can't type `[]` a 100 times if I want `[[]]*100`.

Comment: Replace `[[]]*3` with `Array.new(3) { [] }`

Comment: @JaredGoguen: Precisely correct, same reasoning in Ruby and Python for this.

Comment: Or you can use ``a[1] = [2]``

Comment: In the last three years, askers suspected their problem was the result of a Ruby bug 382 times. It turned out it actually was a bug 3 times. (Source: D. Trump.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland My laughter must’ve been heard in Denver, CO. Brilliant.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I wouldn't know about Denver, but it didn't make it to Victoria.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I bet it’s because [as I was told] Canada has soundproof borders.

Comment: Hint: how many arrays did you create?

Comment: Another way to do the same thing: `[1, 2, 3].each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = [] }` - this way you avoid creating the useless array of arrays, and directly make (and populate) a hash. Also, possibly off-topic, but you might actually be gunning for this: `a = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }`. This will give you an empty hash, but with a new `Array` as a default value for every key. `a[1] << 2; a[2] << 3; a[2] << 4; a` will give you `{1=>[2], 2=>[3, 4]}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected, since when you're creating the second array in `zip` is the same object:

```
a = [1, 2, 3].zip([[]]*3)
 #=> [[1, []], [2, []], [3, []]]
a.map{|aa| aa.last.object_id }
 #=> [70307853627580, 70307853627580, 70307853627580]
```

So, when you try to update that object, it gets reflected across the object `a`:

```
a[0][1] << 2
 #=> [2]
p a
 #=> [[1, [2]], [2, [2]], [3, [2]]]
```

To create an [array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) with separate objects a block can be passed instead. This method is safe to use with mutable objects such as hashes, strings or other arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3].zip( Array.new(3) { [] } )
 #=> [[1, []], [2, []], [3, []]]
a[0][1] << 2
 #=> [2]
p a
 #=> [[1, [2]], [2, []], [3, []]]
```

I would encourage you to read [this article](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2015/02/11/weird-stuff-with-hashes.html) which talks about such scenarios with hashes by Aaron Patterson.

Comment: very nice detailed explanation 1+